# C++ Precedence definitive list

Tags: c++, operators, language-lawyer, operator-precedence

A quick search for C++ precedence yields many attempts.  The disconcerting part is that they are all different.  Most are assuredly wrong, albeit in minor details.

I will include three. The first, from cppreference.com claims there are 16 levels of precedence.  Learn.cpp has 18.
A simpler table at university of Purdue is much simpler.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/31-precedence-and-associativity/

http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~cs240/misc/operators.html

None of these is definitive, but when I looked at the draft ISO standard, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf it did not even have a table, stating that you could figure it out from context.

My questions are 1) is there a good, definitive summary of precedence anywhere?

2) can anyone comment on all the differing "facts" conveyed by these tables?

For example, the first two agree that postincrement/decrement is on the same level as parentheses, what does that mean in practice?

```
(x+1)++
```

makes no sense because x+1 is an rexpr, and obviously parentheses which bracket an expression invalidate postincrement.

```
(*p)++;
```

I have read that postincrement is higher than preincrement, so I would put it just below () [] etc.  What makes it equal (if it is)?

cppreference claims that throw is on the same level as assignment operators.  This seems patently false, since:

```
throw x += 5;
```

should presumably first compute x += 5 before throwing.  learncpp differs, and the third source doesn't mention throw as an operator at all.

This is the first time I have ever seen as an operator.  I admit to not studying the standard for years, but return is a statement, why not throw?

Any comments illuminating bits of the precedence table would be great here.

Comment: "This seems patently false, since:

`throw x += 5;`
should presumably first compute x += 5 before throwing." There's nothing wrong with them having the same precedence. They have right-to-left associativity. If you want to add imaginary parentheses, it's parsed as `throw (x += 5);`.

Comment: In C++, operator precedence is actually defined according to the grammar. The references you cite have `?:` in different places, but doing something like `x ? y : z = 5` will be parsed as `(x) ? (y) : (z = 5)` not because of precedence but because *conditional-expression* can be a *logical-or-expression* `?` *expression* `:` *assignment-expression*.

Comment: I [certainly disagree](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c64f44898e914010) with learncpp putting `?:` above assignment. The standard (or at least N3936) says it groups right-to-left as well, not left-to-right.

Comment: @chris `b=5` in your first example is part of the `?:`, see my comment right before yours.

Comment: Please note that your first question (*is there a good, definitive summary of precedence anywhere*) is off-topic because you are asking for an off-site resource. Interestingly, asking for the table of precedence itself would be on-topic since the answerer could reproduce the table in its answer, so you might want to edit your question.

Comment: @Barry, Yes, the example shows why I disagree. `?:` can't very well have higher precedence if it behaves like that.

Answer (score 4):

Precedence is not a part of the language specification. It is a mnemonic device used by us, humans, to understand the meaning of an expression without recursively analyzing it like an actual parser.

throw, ?: and all assignments in C++ are alternatives in the grammar production *assignment-expression*, defined as follows

```
 assignment-expression:
    conditional-expression
    logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause
    throw-expression
```

Where *conditional-expression* is defined as *logical-or-expression* **?** *expression* **:** *assignment-expression*, *initializer-clause* is another *assignment-expression* (when it isn't a *braced-init-list*), and *throw-expression* is defined as the keyword `throw` followed by an optional `assignment-expression`.

In human terms, we describe this as "same precedence, grouping right to left".

To reuse [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) examples,

`e = a < d ? a++ : a = d` parses as `e = ((a < d) ? (a++) : (a = d))`

and `false ? 7 : throw 3` parses as `false ? 7 : (throw 3)`, and yes, your example of `throw x += 5` parses as `throw (x += 5)`

Comment: Very good answer:). But how exactly is precedence different from a recursive analysis? When we humans analyze an expression. Say 8*5 +7*3. We split it up, and parse(read: calculate) the mupliplications first. That is recursive right?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your three sources, the order is essentially the same - C++ Reference groups throw and ?: together with assignment, which is separate in learncpp. Purdue's is much simpler, but also less specific.

Though it might look a bit complicated, I would recommend using learncpp's as a guideline, since it's the most specific. The parenthesis rule *is* a bit confusing; as a rule of thumb, use them as if they have highest precedence.

On the second part of your question...

```
(x+1)++;
```

certainly won't do anything, as (x+1) returns an r-value, which cannot be assigned to by the ++ operator.

```
(*p)++;
```

dereferences pointer p, and then increments the variable that it pointed to. Because dereferencing is lower than increment, without the parenthesis, it would dereference p and then *increment the pointer*, causing undefined behaviour.

I think the reason it's actually written such that postincrement is the same as () is that parenthesis would be done first anyways. Of course, if the () evaluates to an r-value, it will return an error. Preincrement is lower because if needed, the () has to go first. Take, for example,

```
++(*x);
```

In this case, x must be dereferenced first before incrementing it.

For your last question about throw, the tables list it as evaluated right-to-left. Your snippet of

```
throw x += 5;
```

will evaluate as

```
throw (x += 5);
```

It's listed as an operator because it's apparently an expression. Someone else with more knowledge on exception handling could probably explain this.

Comment: `throw` is indeed an operator.