# in c++,why a=*pr++,c=pr++,a is *pr instead of *c?

Tags: c++

In c++ primer,I found this question ,the book explains this question for that the increment operator（++） is prior to the Solutions to address operator（*） ,for example:

```
a=*p++;
```

It is equal to:

```
a=*(p++);
```

But Why a is equal to the value which is the initial value of p points instead of p++ points.In the second coding,We know that parentheses's priority is the highest,so it should first execute p++,then execute the Solutions to address operator,so it should return the value which p points after it changed its address. But it didn't. Why?I didn't understand that.

Comment: Can you actually post some formatted code?  As is it is pretty hard to understand what your problem is.

Comment: `p++` returns the value of `p` *before* it modifies it - the parentheses don't change anything about that

Comment: I have changed the format

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how does that dupe answer this question?

Comment: @NathanOliver At least the relevant tables are linked in the question. I can't mark dupes to en.cppreference.com unfortunaltely:-P

Feel free to reopen if you don't agree.

Comment: Why you marked my question as duplicate?I just first use this site to ask a question ,

Comment: You are expected to FIRST search for an answer to the question that you think you have...then if you do not find an answer you ask.  If there is already an answer to the question you seem to be asking then it is appropriately marked as duplicate...which it is.  have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276755/c-precedence-definitive-list

Answer (score 3):

> But Why a is equal to the value which is the initial value of `p`?

Because `p++` is a **post** increment, which returns the previous value of `p` before the increment was applied.  So, in `a = *p++`, `a` is assigned the value that `p` originally pointed at before the increment was applied.

It is basically the same as doing this:

```
previous = p;
++p;
a = *previous;
```

Parentheses will not affect that. You can read more in [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).